# How to filter from an array in ios swift

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, unique

I have an array in which I append the values coming from JSON.

like this

```
var tagsarray = [Tagging]()

tagsarray.append(Tagging.init(tags: tempTag[0], selected: false))
tagsarray.append(Tagging.init(tags: tempTag[1], selected: false))
```

**Model**

```
struct Tagging {
private(set) public var tags : String
 public var selected : Bool

init(tags : String, selected : Bool) {
    self.tags = tags
    self.selected = selected
  }
}
```

Now my problem is to filter the array of same values.

Comment: Post more code please

Comment: Add tagging model in post.

Comment: Unrelated but `private(set)` in this case is nonsense in Swift. If you want a constant **declare** a constant: `let tags : String`

Comment: start struct name with capital letter

Comment: What do you mean with values here when you say they are the same, is it `tagging` objects or values within the `tags` property?

Comment: @vadian `private(set)` if valid in Swift if you want allow only read access for property outside of type

Comment: @ManWithBear It's valid but in practice and in this case it's a constant. And there is a (better) syntax for constants.

Comment: @vadian we don't know what other methods `tagging` struct has

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   let filteredArray = tagsarray.filter {$0.tags == "1"}
>   print(filteredArray)
> ```

try this simple filter function

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about order, you can just put all items in Set and convert back to array.
For it your type need to conform to `Hashable`.
If all properties of your type are `Hashable` then you can just add `: Hashable` and compiler will handle rest for you.

```swift
struct tagging: Hashable {
    private(set) public var tags : String
    public var selected : Bool

    init(tags : String, selected : Bool) {
        self.tags = tags
        self.selected = selected
    }
}
tagsarray = Array(Set(tagsarray))
```

But if you need to save order of items, you need to filter by hands. For it you will need `Equatable`. It work same way as `Hashable`, compiler will handle implementation for you.

```swift
struct tagging: Equatable {
    private(set) public var tags : String
    public var selected : Bool

    init(tags : String, selected : Bool) {
        self.tags = tags
        self.selected = selected
    }
}

tagsarray = tagsarray.reduce(into: []) { uniqs, tag in
    guard !uniqs.contains(tag) else { return }
    uniqs.append(tag)
}
```